# Can not convert XSD to Java classes

Tags: java, xml, maven, jaxb

My customer.xsd looks like this.I am trying to convert it into pojo classes
schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'xml.xsd', because

1) could not find the document;

2) the document could not be read;

3) the root element of the document is not `<xsd:schema>`.

I am using maven to convert XSD into Java clases.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsd:schema
        xmlns           = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31"
        xmlns:xsd       = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        targetNamespace = "http://www.demandware.com/xml/impex/customer/2006-10-31"
        elementFormDefault = "qualified">

    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd" />

    <xsd:element name="customers">
        <xsd:complexType mixed="false">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="customer" type="complexType.Customer" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
                <xsd:element name="group-assignment" type="complexType.CustomerGroupAssignment" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <!-- Fake some more top level elements to allow for snippet based JAXB parsing -->
    <xsd:element name="customer" type="complexType.Customer" />

    <xsd:element name="group-assignment" type="complexType.CustomerGroupAssignment">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                Elements of this type are import-only and will never be exported.  
                Furthermore, elements of this type will be handled only if included in
                a customer import file (customer.xsd) but are ignored if included in a 
                customer list import (customerlist2.xsd).
                <p/>
                The reason for this discrepancy is that customer groups are site-specific, 
                and customer import is always done in the context of a site whereas customer 
                list import is not.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>       
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Customer" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="credentials" type="complexType.Credentials" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="profile" type="complexType.Profile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="external-profiles" type="complexType.ExternalProfiles" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="addresses" type="complexType.Addresses" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="customer-groups" type="complexType.CustomerGroups" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                        This element will never appear in a customer list export file (customerlist2.xsd)
                        but may be included in a customer export (customer.xsd).  This element will also 
                        be ignored if specified in a customer list import but will be processed in
                        a customer import.
                        <p/>
                        The reason for this discrepancy is that customer groups are site-specific, 
                        and customer export is always done in the context of a 
                        site where as customer list export is not.
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>            
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="note" type="simpleType.Generic.String.4000" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="customer-no" type="simpleType.Generic.String.100" use="optional" />
        <xsd:attribute name="mode" type="simpleType.ImportMode" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Profile" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="salutation" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="title" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="first-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="second-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="last-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="suffix" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="company-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="job-title" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="email" type="simpleType.Email" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="phone-home" type="simpleType.PhoneNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="phone-business" type="simpleType.PhoneNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="phone-mobile" type="simpleType.PhoneNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="fax" type="simpleType.PhoneNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="birthday" type="xsd:date" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="gender" type="simpleType.Gender" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="creation-date" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="last-login-time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="last-visit-time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="preferred-locale" type="simpleType.Generic.String.10" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="custom-attributes" type="sharedType.CustomAttributes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Credentials" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="login" type="simpleType.Login" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="password" type="complexType.Password" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:documentation>
                    If a customer is managed externally (i.e. provider-id and external-id are specified)
                    then the password is always optional. Otherwise, a password is required for any of
                    the following scenarios:
                        * creation of a new customer
                        * importing a customer in REPLACE mode
                        * changing the login of a customer
                    </xsd:documentation>
                </xsd:annotation>
            </xsd:element>
            <xsd:element name="enabled-flag" type="xsd:boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="password-question" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="password-answer" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="provider-id" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
               <xsd:annotation> 
                   <xsd:documentation>The element 'provider-id' has been deprecated. Use external-profiles to manage provider-id/external-id pairs.</xsd:documentation> 
               </xsd:annotation> 
            </xsd:element>            
            <xsd:element name="external-id" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" >
               <xsd:annotation> 
                   <xsd:documentation>The element 'external-id' has been deprecated. Use external-profiles to manage provider-id/external-id pairs.</xsd:documentation> 
               </xsd:annotation> 
            </xsd:element>            
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.ExternalProfiles" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="external-profile" type="complexType.ExternalProfile" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.ExternalProfile" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="provider-id" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="external-id" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="email" type="simpleType.Email" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="last-login-time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.EncryptionScheme">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="md5" >
                <xsd:annotation> 
                   <xsd:documentation>Support for the md5 encryption algorithm has changed. Passwords imported in md5 will be stored as an scrypt'd value.</xsd:documentation> 
               </xsd:annotation> 
            </xsd:enumeration>
            <xsd:enumeration value="scrypt" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="s0001" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Password">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
            Represents an encrypted or plain value and contains information on how to deal with it during import.

            Import: If the attribute 'encrypted' is set to false, the content of this tag will be encrypted  
            using the new scrypt algorithm. 'encryptionScheme' should be 'null' in this case.
            If the attribute 'encrypted' is set to true, it is assumed that the given password was encrypted
            with the algorithm in 'encryptionScheme' (md5, scrypt, or the internal implementation s0001). 
            The password will be imported 'as is'.

            Export: The attribute 'encrypted' will always be set to true. The attribute 'encryptionScheme'
            will reflect the encryption scheme of the password in the database (md5 (deprecated), scrypt, or the internal implementation s0001). 
            The encrypted password will not be transformed during export.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>    
        <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="simpleType.Generic.String.256">
                <xsd:attribute name="encrypted" type="xsd:boolean" use="required" />
                <xsd:attribute name="encryptionScheme" type="simpleType.EncryptionScheme" />
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.CustomerGroups" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="customer-group" type="complexType.CustomerGroup" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.CustomerGroup" mixed="false">
        <xsd:attribute name="group-id" type="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.256" use="required" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Addresses" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="address" type="complexType.Address" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.Address" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="salutation" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="title" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="first-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="second-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="last-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="suffix" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="company-name" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="job-title" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="address1" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="address2" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="suite" type="simpleType.Generic.String.32" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="postbox" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="city" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="postal-code" type="simpleType.Generic.String.10" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="state-code" type="simpleType.Generic.String.256" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="country-code" type="simpleType.CountryCode" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="phone" type="simpleType.PhoneNumber" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <xsd:element name="custom-attributes" type="sharedType.CustomAttributes" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="address-id" type="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.256" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute name="preferred" type="xsd:boolean" use="optional" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="complexType.CustomerGroupAssignment" mixed="false">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                            Represents the assignment of a customer to a customer group.

                            When a &lt;group-assignment&gt; element is imported, the customer with the specified 
                            customer-no is assigned to the customer group with the specified group-id.  If an assignment 
                            already exists, no change is made.

                            When an element is imported with attribute mode="delete", the assignment of the customer
                            with the specified customer-no to the customer group with the specified group-id is removed.
                            If the customer is not assigned to the group, no change is made.

                            When mode="delete", either the customer-no or group-id attribute can be omitted to remove
                            multiple assignments of customers to customer groups.  If only customer-no is present, any
                            existing assignments of the specified customer to groups are removed.  If only group-id is 
                            present, any existing assignments of customers to the specified group are removed.

                            Assignments can only be created or removed for static customer groups.  A warning message
                            is logged if a specified customer group is dynamic.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:attribute name="mode" type="simpleType.ImportMode" />
        <xsd:attribute name="group-id" type="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.256" />
        <xsd:attribute name="customer-no" type="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.100" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- Shared Complex Types -->

    <xsd:complexType name="sharedType.CustomAttributes" mixed="false">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="custom-attribute" type="sharedType.CustomAttribute" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="sharedType.CustomAttribute" mixed="true">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="value" type="simpleType.Generic.String" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="attribute-id" type="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.256" use="required" />
        <xsd:attribute ref="xml:lang" />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <!-- Simple Types -->

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.ImportMode">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="delete" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Gender">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Allowed string values are the 'int' values defined for the Customer.gender attribute, and additionally the values 'male' and 'female' for backward compatibility.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String" />
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string" />
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String.100">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="100" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String.256">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="256" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String.32">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="32" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String.10">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="10" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.String.4000">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="4000" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <!--  Nonempty string with no leading or trailing whitespace -->
    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.100">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="1" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="100" />
            <xsd:pattern value="\S|(\S(.*)\S)" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Generic.NonEmptyString.256">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="1" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="256" />
            <xsd:pattern value="\S|(\S(.*)\S)" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.CountryCode">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="1" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="2" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Email">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="256" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.Login">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The allowed character set for the login element is
                limited to [A-Z a-z 0-9 .@_-].
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="256" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

    <xsd:simpleType name="simpleType.PhoneNumber">
        <xsd:restriction base="simpleType.Generic.String">
            <xsd:minLength value="0" />
            <xsd:maxLength value="32" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>

</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: Well, instead of posting that sesquipedalian XSD, you should rather tell us *where* you put that schema, and how you configured your plugin(s) in maven!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Old version of xml.xsd you are referencing,so please update this. Kindly replace the following from your xsd.

```
     <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace" schemaLocation="xml.xsd" />
```

Replace above with

```
     <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"  schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml.xsd"/>
```

If you are using eclipse, use jaxb plugin to generate the classes from xsd.